# How to read a lot of txt file in specific folder using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please help me, i have some file txt in folder. I want to read and summary all data become one file txt. How can I do it with python.
for example :

```
folder name : data
file name in that folder : log1.txt
                           log2.txt
                           log3.txt
                           log4.txt
data in log1.txt : Size:         1,116,116,306 bytes
data in log2.txt : Size:         1,116,116,806 bytes
data in log3.txt : Size:         1,457,116,806 bytes
data in log4.txt : Size:         1,457,345,000 bytes
```

My expected output:

```
   a file txt the result.txt and the data is : 1,116,116,306 
                                               1,116,116,806 
                                               1,457,116,806 
                                               1,457,345,000
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough

Comment: If you need to list sizes of files in folder (and this is what can be presumed from expected output) you can use `os.walk()` to gather files and `os.stat('your_file').st_size` to print sizes. You also mention reading and merging, but you don't mention what you want to read and why and how you want to merge.

Comment: `os.path.getsize(path)` is a bit simpler.

Comment: You just to group all the data in one same file, on write down the sizes of all your files in that file ?

Comment: Erna, I'm under the impression that the data in your pre-existing files is sorted by date-time and that you would like the result file to be sorted as well... am I right or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean you want to read the contents of each file and write all of them in to a different file.

```
import os
#returns the names of the files in the directory data as a list
list_of_files = os.listdir("data")
lines=[]
for file in list_of_files:
    f = open(file, "r")
    #append each line in the file to a list
    lines.append(f.readlines())
    f.close()

#write the files to result.txt
result = open("result.txt", "w")
result.writelines(lines)
result.close()
```

If you are looking for size of file instead of the contents.
change the two lines :

```
 f= open(file,"r")
lines.append(f.readlines())
```

to:

```
lines.append(os.stat(file).st_size)
```

Comment: how if i just want to read `1,116,116,306` from `Size:         1,116,116,306 bytes`

Answer (score 1):

File `concat.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os

def main():
    folder = sys.argv[1] # argument contains path
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as result: # result file will be in current working directory
        for path in os.walk(folder).next()[2]: # list all files in provided path
            with open(os.path.join(folder, path), 'r') as source:
                result.write(source.read()) # write to result eachi file

main()
```

Usage `concat.py <your path>`

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to find all files that you are going to read:

   ```
   path = "data"
   files = os.listdir(path)
   ```
2. You have to read all files and for each of them to collect the size and the content:

   ```
   all_sz = {i:os.path.getsize(path+'/'+i) for i in files}
   all_data = ''.join([open(path+'/'+i).read() for i in files])
   ```
3. You need a formatted print:

   ```
   msg = 'this is ...;' 
   sp2 = ' '*4
   sp = ' '*len(msg) + sp2
   print msg + sp2,
   for i in all_sz:
       print sp, "{:,}".format(all_sz[i])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Import `os`. Then list the folder contents using `os.listdir('data')` and store it in an array. For each entry you can get the size by calling `os.stat(entry).st_size`. Each of these entries can now be written to a file.

Combined:

```
import os

outfile = open('result.txt', 'w')
path = 'data'
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    outfile.write(str(os.stat(path + "/" + file).st_size) + '\n')

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If one needs to *merge* sorted files so that the output file is sorted too,
they can use the `merge` method from the `heapq` standard library module.

```
from heapq import merge
from os import listdir

files = [open(f) for f in listdir(path)]
with open(outfile, 'w') as out:
    for rec in merge(*files):
        out.write(rec)
```

Records are kept sorted in lexical order, if one needs something different `merge` accepts a `key=...` optional argument to specify a different ordering function.